# Flexible height for editable NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I've created a very simple demo project with a view based table view and the following `NSTableViewDelegate` implementation

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];
    result.textField.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld Row %ld end", row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row, row];
    return result;
}
```

By setting the `NSTextField` in the cell to word wrap, the text fields automatically get the correct height:

[image: Desired layout]

As soon as I change the behavior of the `NSTextField` from `None` to `Editable`, the text fields only show one line:
[image: Layout when editable]

I've got no idea why — any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update your Developer Tools to Interface Builder 3.1.2 and reset the Layout and Line Breaks settings on the text field. That'll do it!